# C++: Terminate called without an active exception (GCC)

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, exception

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>

static void* busy(void*)
{
  int oldstate ;
  auto result = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,&oldstate) ;
  if (result != 0)
#ifdef NOEXCEPT
    { std::cerr << "pthread_setcanceltype" << std::endl ; abort() ; }
#else
    throw std::runtime_error("pthread_setcanceltype") ;
#endif
  while (true) 
    ;
  return nullptr ;
}

static pthread_t start()
{
  pthread_t t ;
  int result = pthread_create(&t,nullptr,busy,nullptr) ;
  if (result != 0)
    throw std::runtime_error("pthread_create") ;
  return t ;
}

static void terminate(pthread_t t)
{
  auto result = pthread_cancel(t) ;
  if (result != 0) 
    throw std::runtime_error("pthread_cancel()") ;
  result = pthread_join(t,nullptr) ;
  if (result != 0) 
    throw std::runtime_error("pthread_join()") ;
}

int main()
{
  auto t = start() ;
  sleep(1) ; // may not cause an abort otherwise
  terminate(t) ;
  return 0 ;
}
```

This runs fine as long as no optimization (or -O1) is used, e.g. with g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o test test.cc -pthread

However, with -O2 or -O3 the program aborts with the message above.

Also kind of interesting: it runs thru if compiled with -DNOEXCEPT. So it appears, if a thread is cancelled in a function that potentially [sic!] throws an exception, and if optimization is switched on, the program may abort. -- And I can't see any way to prevent this.

It's for me reproducible on amd64 gcc 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 14.04.3) and armv7l gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10).

Can you reproduce this? Do you have an explanation? This behavior seems to be odd (at least to me). I'd be happy to receive some kind of feedback. Thank you!

Comment: I think the place you mention (please link when referring to something on the World Wide Web) was talking about `std::thread` and not about pthreads.

Comment: Another [useful article](https://skaark.wordpress.com/2010/08/26/pthread_cancel-considered-harmful/). Although it is not exactly your problem, it outlines other problem with `pthread_cancel`. Edit: another [similar problem](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2007-06/msg00020.html)

Comment: You are using pthreads, not C++11 threads. There is no thread cancellation in C++11 threads. How naked pthreads interact with C++ exceptions or built-in C++11 thread facilities (which are probably still pthreads inside on your platform, but wrapped in some kind of C++-aware wrapper) is anyone's guess.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Still, the question remains: What is the expected behavior of pthreads and exception (placeholders) in C++? Is there any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Linux (as on most OSes) exceptions are a language-agnostic feature, and pthread cancellation is implemented using language-agnostic exceptions (See e.g. [Cancellation and C++ Exceptions](http://udrepper.livejournal.com/21541.html)).

When a pthread cancellation is delivered to a thread (using a signal, but you don't need to know that) the unwind machinery invokes all the installed personalities so that they can perform language-specific cleanup prior to the thread exiting. (This is pretty cool; it means that as in the above article you can insert a catch block for `abi::__forced_unwind` to detect - though not to prevent - a thread cancellation.)

The problem is that an asynchronous cancellation can occur at any instruction, and the C++ exception tables generated by g++ only handle exceptions occurring at instructions known to be capable of generating exceptions (i.e. but not only calls to exception-throwing functions). If an exception is generated at a point not covered by the C++ tables, the C++ personality panics and terminates the process (hence "terminate called without an active exception").

The reason this is influenced by optimization is that the C++ personality is installed lazily, but with higher optimization levels the compiler might decide to preemptively install the C++ personality. You can guarantee the crash even at lower optimization levels by exercising the C++ exception machinery e.g. with `try { throw 0; } catch (int) {}`.

The simplest fix is to ensure that the C++ personality is not installed in the thread you want to asynchronous cancel. You can ensure this by compiling the thread function as C and not calling any C++ functions from it.

A more hacky and *highly* unsupported solution is to ensure that all the asynchronous cancellation points (that is, all the instructions where the cancelled thread could be when the asynchronous cancellation is received) are *in fact* covered by the C++ unwind tables. Firstly you need to compile with `-fnon-call-exceptions`; secondly you have to ensure that every instruction that could be an asynchronous cancellation point is *between* two points known to be synchronous cancellation points, e.g. `pthread_testcancel`:

```
static void* busy(void*)
{
  int oldstate ;
  auto result = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS,&oldstate) ;
  if (result != 0)
#ifdef NOEXCEPT
    { std::cerr << "pthread_setcanceltype" << std::endl ; abort() ; }
#else
    throw std::runtime_error("pthread_setcanceltype") ;
#endif
  pthread_testcancel();
  for (unsigned i = 1; ; ++i) 
    if (i == 0)
      pthread_testcancel();
  return nullptr ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the insight! :-) If I got it right, the C++ exception handling covers pthreads. It is even advised that pthread cancellation should be implemented on top of C++ exceptions (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.programming.threads/ZSvPGG-79pc). However, to put it bluntly, it doesn't always work with GCC (since its implementation of the exception table doesn't cover all cancellation points). So, the safe way is either to drop asynchronous cancellation, or to fall back to plain C. A workaround may be to introduce additionally cancellation points (as in your example).

Answer (score -1):

> Somebody wrote here that a program aborts "when a thread object goes out of scope and it is in joinable state".

That is what [39.3.1.3/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.thread.destr) [thread destructor] says actually:

> If joinable(), calls std::terminate(). [...] Thus the programmer must ensure that the destructor is never executed while the thread is still joinable.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question altogether.

Comment: Well, actually I replied to the first sentence. The rest of the question is based on a wrong assumption and treats the (let me say) _wrong_ threads, so... it is tagged `C++11` and threads are part of the Standard Template Library since C++11 as far as I know.

Comment: Yeah, that is misleading. (Actually I use std::thread, however with native handle access. After digging into the problem for a while I recognized it's a pthread issue.) I fixed my posting accordingly.

Comment: Right. I won't drop the answer, for it answered the original question.